# Is Prop a subtype of Set?

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I am surprised to see the following behavior:

```
Check ((True : Prop) : Set).

=============================================

(True : Prop) : Set
     : Set
```

It however does not work the other way around:

```
Check ((True : Set) : Prop).

=============================================

Error:
The term "True : Set" has type "Set" while it is expected to have type 
"Prop" (universe inconsistency: Cannot enforce Set <= Prop).
```

It very much looks like `Prop <: Set`, but I have never seen that stated explicitly anywhere. My doubts are backed by the differences between those two universes, as each seems so have features which the other lacks. I also have not heard that Coq has any sort of subtyping to be honest.

How is it then? Is `Prop` a true subtype of `Set` or is there some other magic going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I currently don't have enough reputation to comment on your question, here's a short answer: Yes, `Prop` is indeed a subtype of `Set`. Check out https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/cic.html#subtyping-rules, rule #4.

Intuitively, `Set` is the sort of all "small" data types, while `Prop` intends to be the sort of all logical propositions. You can convert from `Prop` to `Set` but not the other way around.